# I get 500 error when using laravel database notification. I'm using vue js for the ajax

Tags: laravel, vue.js, notifications, axios

I want to make a notification when user2 approves a friend request from user1. so user 1 gets a notification. This is my code, but the result is 500 errors.

Notification:

```
    private $sender;
    private $current;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($sender, $current)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->current = $current;
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'sender' => $this->sender,
            'message' => 'Your friend request has been accepted.',
            'currentTime' => $this->current
        ];
    }
```

Controller:

```
   public function acceptFriendRequest($id)
    {
        $sender = User::findOrFail($id);
        Auth::user()->acceptFriendRequest($sender);

        $current = Carbon::now();
        $current = new Carbon();

        User::findOrFail($id)->notify(new FriendRequestAccepted());
    }
```

My Vue Component:

```
     acceptfr: function (id) {
       axios.post("/friend-request-accept/" + id)
           .then(function (response) {
              console.log("Accept FR Success");

           })
           .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
           });
     },
```

Route:

```
   Route::post('/friend-request-accept/{id}', 'FriendshipController@acceptFriendRequest');
```

in Browser Console:

```
    Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:653)
    at settle (app.js:899)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:166)
```

Note:
Everything works, if not using notification.

Comment: 500 errors come with a useful error message somewhere in your Laravel or webserver logs. (Chances are if you inspect the AJAX request's response in your browser's Network console, the details will be there as well.)

Comment: Cheers!! Thanks, Now I know the problem is! And, its working now. I just forgot to php artisan event:generate for Notification Event...